# SQL Server 2008 trigger error while parsing

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm just learning the basics of how triggers work/what the best uses for them are and I found a tutorial online just to get the look and feel of them.  The below trigger doesn't run and the error given is `incorrect syntax was encountered while parsing go`

```
set nocount on
create table source1(sou_id int identity, sou_desc varchar(10))
go
create trigger tr_source1_insert
on source1
for insert as print getdate()
go insert source1 (sou_desc) values ('test 1')
```

can someone explain what's going on here, and what i should've expected to see?

edit: little things were fixed, still seeing the same error

Comment: I'm sure you meant `set nocount ON`...

Comment: yes, that was a misspelling, the code was spelled correctly.  thanks for catching.

Comment: I also can't help but notice a missing close paren on your insert statement...

Comment: Insert newline after GO in last line.

Comment: @nik thanks :).  i assume GO always has to be on its own line?

Comment: if you are just learning teh basics of triggers, you should know that you would never really want to write a trigger that just selects or prints something.  Triggers should be for actions. Further, in SQL server, triggers are run once per transaction, so iyou must be able to handle multiple recirds being inserted/deleted. or updated. AS you progress in your learning, do not make the mistake of trying to set a values from the inserted or deleted table to a scalar variable and alawys test triggers using a mulitple record insert/update or delelte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
set nocount on
    create table source1(sou_id int identity, sou_desc varchar(10))
    go
    create trigger tr_source1_insert
    on source1
    for insert as 
    print getdate()
    go 
    insert source1 values ('test 1')
```

'Go' statement needs to be on a separate line.